# Connection Fail-over : How to support simple connection fail-over it is possible to define multiple endpoints (host and port pairs)?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, failover

I configured the postgres replication and it works. By following:

Standby for Postgresql Windows - DevOps
http://www.openmakesoftware.com/insights/postgresql-hot-standby-for-windows/

I am using NPGSQL library to connect to database via EF 6.

I understand this facility is there in Java JDBC. But trying to figure out in .NET

Please help me out how we can write the connection string or another way to ensure failover in NPGSQL.

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Vivek Acharya

Answer (score 0):

Npgsql doesn't currently provide any sort of connection failover facility. You're welcome to open an issue requesting it on http://github.com/npgsql/npgsql

Comment: Thanks for giving response.